# How to disable window resizing and only put fullscreen mode

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am doing a modpack for the first time and I would like to be able to disable the resizing in the window and that the game can only be used in full screen because when the window is resized my game menu loses its shape completely, if someone helps me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: First off, StackOverflow is a place for programming related questions. 
Secondly, please try not to force your users to fullscreen. This is generally a bad idea and especially bad concerning accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m having a little trouble understanding the purpose here of forcing fullscreen. As Siphalor said, I don’t think it’s a good solution.
I guess the problem you have is that your buttons have a fixed size, so when you enlarge the window, they don’t fit.

A solution could be to manage the size of the buttons in proportion to the size of the window and not to put a fixed size on the buttons and block any change in the size of the window.

Comment: Okey i understand, thanks.